# elasticsearch range query ignored by range aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a `range aggregation` over `maxPrice` to get the count of documents for each of the prices.

I use a `range query` to set max values for `maxPrice`. The result of the query is ok. When i set the range f.e. to lte 20, the correct documents are displayed.

**The problem:**

The `range aggregation` shows doc_count > 0 for prices that are greater than those set in the range of range query

**My question:**

How can i get a range aggregation related to the range query?

```
GET test-faceted-search/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "field_value_factor": {
        "field": "ranking",
        "factor": 0.0001,
        "modifier": "ln1p",
        "missing": 1
      },
      "score_mode": "avg",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "find me",
                "fields": [
                  "name^100",
                  "altname^80",
                  "cat^20"
                ],
                "fuzziness": 1,
                "operator": "and",
                "type": "best_fields"
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "maxPrice": {
                  "lte": 20
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "pricefilter": {
      "range": {
        "field": "maxPrice",
          "ranges": [
            {
              "to": 10
            },
            {
              "to": 25
            }
          ]
        }
      }
  }
}
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Can you post your result ? I just tried that in my machine with dummy data and things are working as expected.

Comment: thx for your time

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

I missed, that i have to add the `from` parameter to the range aggregation.

```
"aggs": {
    "pricefilter": {
      "range": {
        "field": "maxPrice",
          "ranges": [
            {
              "from": 0.1
              "to": 10
            },
            {
              "from": 10.01
              "to": 25
            }
          ]
        }
      }
  }
```